# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am new to spring and while executing declarative transaction management application.

I am getting the below error message when I am trying to Run my application.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at FundTransferUseCase.main(FundTransferUseCase.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.class$(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:208)
at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.createPointcutDefinition(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:536)
at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parsePointcut(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:473)
at org.springframework.aop.config.ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:142)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1255)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 27 more
```

in applicationcontext.xml file the below code is written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
```

As I am new to stackoverflow so I am not able to post the image file of the jars which I have been used ...

So here is the link for the image of the jars i have used...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj4aX.png

Comment: As per the dependency I can see there are multiple spring version of jars, you can exclude spring.jar from the list as you have individually added spring-beans, orm, transaction etc.

Comment: is this ur full content of applicationcontext.xml or u have some thing else in applicationcontext.xml?